# PHP Imagick::getImageResolution() returns [0, 0] (array with 2 c zeros)

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using Imagick on a Windows 7 Xampp server. After a while, I was able to install the Imagick extension.

Now, I'm running this code:

```
<?php
    $image = new Imagick(realpath($path));
    $imageResolution = $image->getImageResolution();
    var_dump($imageResolution);
?>
```

Result is:

```
array (size=2)
    'x' => float 0
    'y' => float 0
```

Doesn't matter what Image I use. They all got the same result.

I tried using: getImageGeometry() and I did get a real result but it's not what I need. This is just to say the extension is at least partially working.

Could it be some Windows problem? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing this issue only with PHP. However, it's working fine in ruby on the same machine. seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Not all images have a resolution set. The resolution is the "dots per inch" that the image is meant to be printed at. If that wasn't set when the image was saved, it just won't be there.

Did you mean [Imagick::getImageWidth](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagewidth.php) and Imagick::getImageHeight ?